# Unable to grant SET_ANIMATION_SCALE permission programmatically

Tags: android, animation, permissions

I need to grant my device permission to change automation settings of the device it is running on (for testing purpose).

I have added to manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ANIMATION_SCALE"/>
```

And in my Activity on resume:

```
String[] permissions = new String[1];
permissions[0] = Manifest.permission.SET_ANIMATION_SCALE;
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getCurrentActivity(), permissions, 0);
Log.d("ISGRANTED", " " + (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getCurrentActivity(), permissions[0]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED));
```

And nothing happens. I test on Android Api 23+ and I don't get any dialog to get the permission. Log returns:

> 06-30 15:03:32.757 17771-17799/my.app.package D/ISGRANTED:  false

But if I replace `permisions[0]` with `Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS` (which is also in my manifest above SET_ANIMATION_SCALE permission) then it works. Dialog appears and log returns true.

What's the problem?

Comment: Obviously because: *Not for use by third-party applications.*

Comment: Do you know any other way to disable animations in AVD after launching it with -wipe-data parameter? If I could do it from terminal then it's fine too I guess.

Comment: How could that be working then? https://github.com/metova/Cappuccino They are using same permission. Maybe I am missing something... hmm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at my Gradle plugin, Cappuccino. It automates the process of disabling system animations for Espresso testing. There are detailed instructions on [Github](https://github.com/metova/Cappuccino).

Comment: Thank you. I have already written gradle plugin for my own purposes by taking inspiration from your code. It gave me also some insight how to change more device settings from code by using reflection. It was good study for me :)

Comment: I'd love to see your plugin! Would you share the link?

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://github.com/MindMac/Android-PermissionsLevelDescMap/blob/master/permissions.py) or [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml), because it's not for use by third-party applications:

`"android.permission.SET_ANIMATION_SCALE" : ["signature|system|development", "Modify the global animation scaling factor. Not for use by third-party applications."],`

**ProtectionLevel** ([from here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#protectionLevel)):

> **signature   2** A permission that the system is to grant only if the requesting application is signed with the same certificate as the application that declared the permission. If the certificates match, the system automatically grants the permission without notifying the user or asking for the user's explicit approval.
>
> **system  0x10**  Old synonym for "privileged".
>
> **privileged  0x10**   Additional flag from base permission type: this permission can also be granted to any applications installed as privileged apps on the system image. Please avoid using this option, as the signature protection level should be sufficient for most needs and works regardless of exactly where applications are installed. This permission flag is used for certain special situations where multiple vendors have applications built in to a system image which need to share specific features explicitly because they are being built together.
>
> **development  0x20**  Additional flag from base permission type: this permission can also (optionally) be granted to development applications.